# Regarding the decomposition of a tensor as an antisymmetric and symmetric part

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I have seen for two index tensor that the sum of symmetric and anti symmetric part is the total tensor again.. but is it true for higher index tensor? I thought it was but then I saw this diagram in penrose:

> [image]
>
> Page-241, Road to Reality

In Index notation, it can be written that:

$$ T_{[abc] } =   \frac{1}{3!}(T_{abc} + T_{cab} + T_{bca} - T_{bac} - T_{acb} - T_{cba})$$

and,

$$ T_{(abc) } =  \frac{1}{3!}( T_{abc} + T_{bca} + T_{ca b} + T_{bac} + T_{a cb} + T_{cba})$$

It seems so here that $T_{abc} \neq T_{[abc] } + T_{(abc)}$, if this is the case what would one call the part of the tensor belonging to the difference:

$$ T_{abc} - T_{[abc] } - T_{(abc)}$$

Comment: May be circulant symmetric tensor?

Comment: Could you explain the name? @BinxuWang王彬旭 Edit: due to invariance under circular change of indice?

Comment: The decomposition is given by the decomposition of $V\otimes V\otimes V$ into the irreducible representations of $GL(n)$. This in turn is characterized using Young tableaux. This might be explained in one of Penrose's books. The general case is presented in a Duke Math Journal article by Berger-Bryant-Griffiths, and they cite Weyl's book "The Classical Groups".

Comment: Yeah... I name it like that just because the symmetry with rotation of indices @Aplateofmomos

Comment: See section 4.1.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.10752.pdf

Comment: To expand on Deane's comment, look up "Schur functor" and "Schur-Weyl duality". A place to do that is Fulton/Harris: Representation Theory. Whether this is a good place to look it up I am not sure. I don't like the exposition there, imo it is not very clear, but this is the only textbook I know of where they are treated. I'm sure there are many others as well though.